# Bound on chromatic numbers of union of graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

If I have a vertex-set $V$ and two graphs $G, H$ on $V$, it is easy to show that the chromatic number $\chi (G \cup H) \leq \chi (G) \chi (H)$.

My question now is, whether $\chi (G \cup H) \leq \chi (G) + \chi (H)$ is also true; I guess this is not the case, but I couldn't find any counterexample. Does someone know one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V$ be the vertices of a hexagon.  Let $G$ be the graph that connects each node to its neighbors and second-nearest neighbors.  Then $\chi(G)=3$, since the vertices can be colored "RGBRGB", and the inclusion of triangles means that $G$ is not $2$-colorable.  Let $H$ be the graph connecting each node to its diametric opposite (i.e., three disjoint edges).  Clearly $\chi(H)=2$.  But $G\cup H=K_6$, so $$\chi(G\cup H)=6 > 5=\chi(G)+\chi(H).$$

Comment: What was your thought process ? How did you think of a counter example ?

Comment: Just that $3\cdot 2 > 3+2$ is minimal for the product being greater than the sum, and $K_6$ is the smallest graph with chromatic number $6$; so I looked for edge decompositions of $K_6$ into graphs with chromatic numbers $3$ and $2$.

Answer (score 2):

The edges of the complete graph on $n$ vertices can be covered using roughly $\log n$ bipartite graphs; so there exists a graph $G$ and bipartite graph $H$ such that adding $H$ to $G$ increases the chromatic number by $\dfrac{n}{\log n}$.

Comment: Nice... so not only is the inequality violated, but it's violated by arbitrarily large amounts.